# Handling of Retrial of Failed Transactions

Tags: java, transactions, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to implement retrying failed transactions. For this what we have done  One of my EAR is trying to request to 3rd party if it is failed it writes all transaction to a file (In a CSV file comma seperated each  request).
Ex: 
failed Soap Request 1,
failed Soap Request 2,

My Other EAR is running a scheduler what does it do it reads all transaction.

If my file is in reading or writing mode, it is not proceeded at that moment. It would be proceed if only It is not in reading or writing mode. For this what we do, we change the name of file by appending `_locked`. So If writing thread sees locked file it creates a new file for writing and reading process skips this file.

During reading we put all failed transaction to `JMS` Queue and consumer is making request to 3rd party again for each request. Success and Failed transaction I have to write into other directory  So that Failed transactions can be manually checked(For refunding).

Question:
1). I was wondering what If my server goes down and I didn't get response from 3rd party. So from `ActiveMQ`, my transaction object is already consumed from queue but in further processing  It is lost. So is It possible to manually acknowledge `ActiveMQ` after I get response. But I think it would slow down my request response processing for large number of request.

2) What If I have to retry 3 times for each request. So what is in my mind I would process each file for failed request I would write into other file in directory named as **RETRIED_ONCE**.

I have to traverse again If there is no folder for **RETRIED_TWICE** for failed transaction in RETRIED_ONCE. I would create and write a CSV file into that folder. If any transaction that is retried in  **RETRIED_TWICE**, will go into failed folder and those transactions will be looked manually.

For every Hour my scheduler would scan those three folder and writes failed transaction accordingly.

Is there a better way than this?

Or Should i create two `JMS` Queue for **RETRIED_ONCE** and **RETRIED_TWICE**.

Comment: I would store the failed transactions in the database with a column named "number_of_retries" to and update it on every failed execution. Also, ActiveMQ is transactional, so if you read from the JMS queue and your processing crashes, the object is automatically returned to the ActiveMQ queue... as long as you haven't COMMITTED the transaction yet.

Comment: If you are 1000 request per second. Still you would save failed transactions requests into database? So When would you persist things into a file rather than a database?  I used to assume that database would be heavy for such operations.

Comment: I still would. Or you could just store the file name in the database to make it lightweight. The thing is, databases offer you safety in the form of transactionality and networked persistence in a way that a file system cannot provide well.

Comment: @the-impaler These two projects have different database and first time I am getting failed transaction for retrying purpose, is in CSV format. So i can not get or save first failed transaction in database that is persisted by other project. What I can do I have to retry 3 times for failed transactions, I can create a new table for the same and do my  processing. What do you think its a good idea?